# Agora Unity - PushAudioFrame

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc, agora.io

I'm Using Agor SDK 2.9.2.2 within Unity Platform, to integrate a web broadcasting live.

I tryed to use the pushAudioFrame feature in order to  :

- Grab a float [] from an audioListener
- Send it as byte[] into an AudioFrame,

Whichever way I try SDK receives zero data, or unity just crashes, i'm sure issues in my code are multiple, but couldnt find any successfull example on the web, just ONE unanswered post from a chinese guy, and  I'm not allowed from europe to participate thread...

Actually following code is used:

// Before Joining Channel

`mRtcEngine.SetAudioProfile(AUDIO_PROFILE_TYPE.AUDIO_PROFILE_MUSIC_STANDARD,AUDIO_SCENARIO_TYPE.AUDIO_SCENARIO_EDUCATION);
mRtcEngine.SetExternalAudioSource(true, 16000, 1);`

// On Audio Filter Read

```
`
virtual public void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
        {
            if (GrabSceneAudio)
            {   
                Int16[] intData = new Int16[data.Length];
                //converting in 2 steps : float[] to Int16[], //then Int16[] to Byte[]

                Byte[] bytesData = new Byte[data.Length * 2];
                //bytesData array is twice the size of
                //dataSource array because a float converted in Int16 is 2 bytes.

                var rescaleFactor = 32767; //to convert float to Int16

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    intData[i] = (short)(data[i] * rescaleFactor);
                    Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[2];
                    byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(intData[i]);
                    byteArr.CopyTo(bytesData, i * 2);
                }
                _externalAudioFrameBuffer = bytesData;

                PushExternalAudioFrame();
            }
        }
`
```

// Finally push Audioframe to SDK

```
`
virtual protected void PushExternalAudioFrame()
        {        
            _externalAudioFrame = new AudioFrame();

            _externalAudioFrame.type = AUDIO_FRAME_TYPE.FRAME_TYPE_PCM16;
            _externalAudioFrame.samples = 256;
            _externalAudioFrame.bytesPerSample = 2;
            _externalAudioFrame.samplesPerSec = 16000;
            _externalAudioFrame.channels = 1;
            _externalAudioFrame.buffer = _externalAudioFrameBuffer;

            if (mRtcEngine != null)
            {
                int a = mRtcEngine.PushAudioFrame(_externalAudioFrame);         
            }
        }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I added some changes to your posted code and tested it in the demo application. You may give it a try.

https://gist.github.com/icywind/8d1d6ad9831402bea8e5852933eb4eb9

or here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using agora_gaming_rtc;
using agora_utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections;


// this is an example of using Agora Unity SDK
// It demonstrates:
// How to enable video
// How to join/leave channel
// 
public class TestHelloUnityVideo
{

    // instance of agora engine
    private IRtcEngine mRtcEngine;
    AudioSource audioSource;
    MonoBehaviour monoProxy;

    public int AudioChannels = 1;

    // load agora engine
    public void loadEngine(string appId)
    {
        // start sdk
        Debug.Log("initializeEngine");

        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Engine exists. Please unload it first!");
            return;
        }

        // init engine
        mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(appId);

        // enable log
        mRtcEngine.SetLogFilter(LOG_FILTER.DEBUG | LOG_FILTER.INFO | LOG_FILTER.WARNING | LOG_FILTER.ERROR | LOG_FILTER.CRITICAL);
    }

    public void join(string channel)
    {
        Debug.Log("calling join (channel = " + channel + ")");

        if (mRtcEngine == null)
            return;

        // set callbacks (optional)
        mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = onJoinChannelSuccess;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined = onUserJoined;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline = onUserOffline;

        // enable video
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
        // allow camera output callback
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();

        /// BEFORE JOINING CHANNEL

        // mRtcEngine.SetAudioProfile(AUDIO_PROFILE_TYPE.AUDIO_PROFILE_MUSIC_HIGH_QUALITY, AUDIO_SCENARIO_TYPE.AUDIO_SCENARIO_GAME_STREAMING);

        mRtcEngine.SetAudioProfile(AUDIO_PROFILE_TYPE.AUDIO_PROFILE_MUSIC_STANDARD, AUDIO_SCENARIO_TYPE.AUDIO_SCENARIO_EDUCATION);
        mRtcEngine.SetExternalAudioSource(true, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioChannels);

        // join channel
        mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(channel, null, 0);

        // Optional: if a data stream is required, here is a good place to create it
        int streamID = mRtcEngine.CreateDataStream(true, true);
        Debug.Log("initializeEngine done, data stream id = " + streamID);
    }


    public bool GrabSceneAudio = true;


    //// OnAudioListenerRender
    virtual public void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
    {
        if (GrabSceneAudio)
        {
            short[] intData = new short[data.Length];
            //converting in 2 steps : float[] to Int16[], //then Int16[] to Byte[]

            byte[] bytesData = new byte[data.Length * 2];
            //bytesData array is twice the size of
            //dataSource array because a float converted in Int16 is 2 bytes.

            var rescaleFactor = 32767; //to convert float to Int16

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                float sample = data[i];
                if (sample > 1) sample = 1;
                else if (sample < -1) sample = -1;

                intData[i] = (short)(sample * rescaleFactor);
                byte[] byteArr = new byte[2];
                byteArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(intData[i]);
                byteArr.CopyTo(bytesData, i * 2);
            }

            PushExternalAudioFrame(bytesData, channels);
        }
    }


    const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    /// FINALLY PUSH FRAME INTO STREAM
    // _externalAudioFrameBuffer.Length = samples * channels * bytesPerSample
    IEnumerator CoAudioRender()
    {
        int channels = audioSource.clip.channels;
        float[] samples = new float[audioSource.clip.samples * channels];
        audioSource.clip.GetData(samples, 0);
        GrabSceneAudio = true;
        int SourceDataIndex = channels * audioSource.timeSamples;
        //int SourceDataIndex = channels * (audioSource.clip.samples - 120000);
        Debug.LogWarning("CoAudioRender started. Found audio samples = " +
            samples.Length + " channels = " + audioSource.clip.channels);

        while (audioSource != null && audioSource.isActiveAndEnabled && audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            int readSamples = (int)(SAMPLE_RATE * Time.deltaTime); // SamplesRate * elapsedTime => number of samples to read
            int delta = channels * readSamples;
            float[] copySample = new float[delta];
            if (readSamples + SourceDataIndex / channels <= audioSource.clip.samples)
            {
                Array.Copy(samples, SourceDataIndex, copySample, 0, delta);
            }
            else // wrap
            {
                int cur2EndCnt = samples.Length - SourceDataIndex;
                int wrap2HeadCnt = delta - cur2EndCnt;
                Array.Copy(samples, SourceDataIndex, copySample, 0, cur2EndCnt);
                Array.Copy(samples, 0, copySample, cur2EndCnt, wrap2HeadCnt);
            }
            SourceDataIndex = (SourceDataIndex + delta) % samples.Length;

            OnAudioFilterRead(copySample, channels);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        GrabSceneAudio = false;
        Debug.LogWarning("Done Audio Render coroutine...");
    }

    virtual protected void PushExternalAudioFrame(byte[] _externalAudioFrameBuffer, int channels)
    {
        AudioFrame _externalAudioFrame = new AudioFrame();

        int bytesPerSample = 2;

        _externalAudioFrame.type = AUDIO_FRAME_TYPE.FRAME_TYPE_PCM16;
        _externalAudioFrame.samples = _externalAudioFrameBuffer.Length / (channels * bytesPerSample);
        _externalAudioFrame.bytesPerSample = bytesPerSample;
        _externalAudioFrame.samplesPerSec = SAMPLE_RATE;
        _externalAudioFrame.channels = channels;
        _externalAudioFrame.buffer = _externalAudioFrameBuffer;

        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            int a = mRtcEngine.PushAudioFrame(_externalAudioFrame);
        }
    }


    public string getSdkVersion()
    {
        string ver = IRtcEngine.GetSdkVersion();
        if (ver == "2.9.1.45")
        {
            ver = "2.9.2";  // A conversion for the current internal version#
        }
        else
        {
            if (ver == "2.9.1.46")
            {
                ver = "2.9.2.2";  // A conversion for the current internal version#
            }
        }
        return ver;
    }

    public void leave()
    {
        Debug.Log("calling leave");

        if (mRtcEngine == null)
            return;

        // leave channel
        mRtcEngine.LeaveChannel();
        // deregister video frame observers in native-c code
        mRtcEngine.DisableVideoObserver();
    }

    // unload agora engine
    public void unloadEngine()
    {
        Debug.Log("calling unloadEngine");

        // delete
        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            IRtcEngine.Destroy();  // Place this call in ApplicationQuit
            mRtcEngine = null;
        }
    }


    public void EnableVideo(bool pauseVideo)
    {
        if (mRtcEngine != null)
        {
            if (!pauseVideo)
            {
                mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
            }
            else
            {
                mRtcEngine.DisableVideo();
            }
        }
    }

    // accessing GameObject in Scnene1
    // set video transform delegate for statically created GameObject
    public void onSceneHelloVideoLoaded()
    {
        // Attach the SDK Script VideoSurface for video rendering
        GameObject quad = GameObject.Find("Quad");
        if (ReferenceEquals(quad, null))
        {
            Debug.Log("BBBB: failed to find Quad");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            quad.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        }

        GameObject cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        if (ReferenceEquals(cube, null))
        {
            Debug.Log("BBBB: failed to find Cube");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cube.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        }

        GameObject game = GameObject.Find("GameController");
        if (game != null)
        {
            monoProxy = game.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
            audioSource = game.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            monoProxy.StartCoroutine(CoAudioRender());
        }
    }

    // implement engine callbacks
    private void onJoinChannelSuccess(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        Debug.Log("JoinChannelSuccessHandler: uid = " + uid);
        GameObject textVersionGameObject = GameObject.Find("VersionText");
        textVersionGameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SDK Version : " + getSdkVersion();
    }

    // When a remote user joined, this delegate will be called. Typically
    // create a GameObject to render video on it
    private void onUserJoined(uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        Debug.Log("onUserJoined: uid = " + uid + " elapsed = " + elapsed);
        // this is called in main thread

        // find a game object to render video stream from 'uid'
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(go, null))
        {
            return; // reuse
        }

        // create a GameObject and assign to this new user
        VideoSurface videoSurface = makeImageSurface(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(videoSurface, null))
        {
            // configure videoSurface
            videoSurface.SetForUser(uid);
            videoSurface.SetEnable(true);
            videoSurface.SetVideoSurfaceType(AgoraVideoSurfaceType.RawImage);
            videoSurface.SetGameFps(30);
        }
    }

    public VideoSurface makePlaneSurface(string goName)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);

        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        go.name = goName;
        // set up transform
        go.transform.Rotate(-90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        float yPos = UnityEngine.Random.Range(3.0f, 5.0f);
        float xPos = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-2.0f, 2.0f);
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.25f, 0.5f, .5f);

        // configure videoSurface
        VideoSurface videoSurface = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        return videoSurface;
    }

    private const float Offset = 100;
    public VideoSurface makeImageSurface(string goName)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject();

        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        go.name = goName;

        // to be renderered onto
        go.AddComponent<RawImage>();

        // make the object draggable
        go.AddComponent<UIElementDragger>();
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        if (canvas != null)
        {
            go.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
        }
        // set up transform
        go.transform.Rotate(0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
        float xPos = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Offset - Screen.width / 2f, Screen.width / 2f - Offset);
        float yPos = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Offset, Screen.height / 2f - Offset);
        go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3f, 4f, 1f);

        // configure videoSurface
        VideoSurface videoSurface = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        return videoSurface;
    }
    // When remote user is offline, this delegate will be called. Typically
    // delete the GameObject for this user
    private void onUserOffline(uint uid, USER_OFFLINE_REASON reason)
    {
        // remove video stream
        Debug.Log("onUserOffline: uid = " + uid + " reason = " + reason);
        // this is called in main thread
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(uid.ToString());
        if (!ReferenceEquals(go, null))
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(go);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @rick-cheng. Thanks for superuseful example. With it I am able to stream audio to agora from Unity. However, the sound on the receiving end has a low frequency noise, and some reverb. Default microphone streaming does not have this problem (I am using AgoraAdvancedDemo projects' App Sharing), so I am guessing the issue lies in how the AudioFrame is constructed in your sample. Please let me know how to debug/fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @eight, I think we got your question on other channels, but let me address this question here so it can benefit others on SO.  Please note that in my example, I use specific sample rate that pertains to my sample audio clip.  It may be different for the resources that you are using.  A little configuration and math will be required to set this right. Check my code around the CoAudioRender() method and make it to suit your environment.